# Making sure user enters a positive number

Tags: excel, vba, function, user-defined-functions

Having problem in VBA user defined function. How to make sure user enters a positive number and the function asks for another entry

This is the code that I have written. The user has to enter the value of radius, height and liquid length. The value obviously cannot be negative but my code provides answer for absurd values as well. How do i make sure this does not happen
Also, H is assumed to be greater than twice the radius

```
Option Explicit

Function tank(R As Double, H As Double, d As Double) As Double
Dim v As Double
If R >= 0 And H >= 0 And d >= 0 Then
    If d <= R Then
        v = (4 * Atn(1) * (2) * (3 * R - d)) / 3
    
    ElseIf d > R And d <= H - R Then
        v = (4 * Atn(1) * 2 * R ^ (3)) / 3 + 4 * Atn(1) * R ^ (2) * (d - R)
    
    ElseIf d > H - R And d <= H Then
        v = ((4 * Atn(1) * 4 * R ^ (3)) / 3) + (4 * Atn(1) * R ^ (2) * (H - 2 * R)) - ((4 * Atn(1) * (H - d) ^ (2)) * (3 * R - H + d)) / 3
    
    End If
    tank = v
End If
End Function
```

Comment: Why not just use absolute() ?  assuming any number with or without sign is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Then, replace this (if I correctly understood your question...):

```
If R >= 0 And H >= 0 And d >= 0 Then
```

with (in fact, add the last condition):

```
If R >= 0 And H >= 0 And d >= 0 And H > R*2 Then
```

And it would be good telling to the user that something is wrong. I would introduce a `Else` and a message telling that the input is wrong.